# Jquery post search criteria to third party api

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am new to Jquery so I might be asking a basic question. I need help writing a function for the below scenario. Thank you!

I have a search page where users can search by all or any of these 4 combined options.
1) free text - text box

```
<input class="search-placeholder ml-16" type="text" name="search">
```

2) search by miles from a location

```
    <select class="mile-counter"><option value="10">10 miles</option><option value="20">20 miles</option></select>      <input type="text" name="location" class="location" placeholder="Enter Zip      or City">
```

3) click on different buttons which are considered attributes

```
let res = response.reduce((obj, item) => {               obj[item.subSection] = obj[item.subSection] || [];               obj[item.subSection].push(item.name);               return obj;             }, {});               // get values array and iterate              Object.keys(res).forEach(function(k) {               // generate h3 ith subSection value and append               $('div.programs').append(               $('<div class="section">' + k + '</div>')                   //$('<h3>', {text: k})                 )                 // generate buttons and append                     .append(res[k].map(v =>                         $(`<button class="button">                         <img class="programs-icons" src="/wwwroot/images/${v}.svg"                onerror="imgError(this);">                         ${v}                       </button>`)                     ))                 })
```

4) pass in a population percentage number ex:10, 20,30

```
<div class="population-text">Top 10 Population</div>
```

I need to call a third party API(ApiSearch/5.3/SearchCriteria) and pass in all the user's searching criteria in the format of

```
 {
"text": "string",
 "attributes": [
    "string"
],
  "Population": 0
}
```

Comment: can you add some html and js you have tried

Comment: `get()` in jQuery just returns the result stack as an array.  There are various ways to find elements on the page, but without more specific details about your page structure, can't really help you much.  Edit: Unless when you say Get() you are referring to `$.get()` which is entirely different.

Comment: Updated question with more information. @taplar I am assuming i want a $.get() since I will want to get back data from this third party api based on the search criteria I sent to it.

Comment: I would advise you to review http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/ and the proceeding "Working with Selections" pages.  They should explain a lot of the basics around selecting elements on a page.  At which point it's just a question of you constructing your object to be stringified later.

Comment: Anyone able to help me out with writing the function to call the API? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/  Ajax is also covered in the api and in the learn site.